# Grand Theft Auto V story mode

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm going to get GTA 5, but I don't want to have to do all the missions. I just want to run around, steal cars, and stuff. is there a mode where i don't have to do missions?

Comment: I implore you to at least start doing missions, as you may find them more fun than running around. The missions provide goals and objectives, which can be fun to complete. If at any point during missions you decide you would rather muck around instead, you are completely able to, but I think it's worth giving the missions a bit of trial as they may make the game more fun.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no such mode. You will have to finish a few mandatory missions until you gain access to free roaming. From that point on, you can simply ignore any and all missions, if that's how you want to enjoy the game.

Even if you wish to play multiplayer only, you will need to get through the single player tutorial first.

Comment: This answer is correct. As a supplement to this answer, it may be possible to download a save file if this is for the PC (from online or a friend) that is maybe 100% completion  to allow unlocking everything, and having money etc.

Answer (score 0):

No. GTA 5 is free(freedom) intrinsically and you don't have to do anything to be able to roam around freely. But if you don't do the missions, some contents may not be accessible, like advanced weapons, properties, certain hobbies and pastimes (parachuting, golfing, etc.).

Alternatively, you can Google for other people's save files and import them. There are plenty of them online and provide a variety of Story Mode progress. You can play around with those saves.